# Browser crashing on frequently data receiving via socket.io

Tags: performance, node.js, browser, socket.io

I have a live single page streaming application at node.js depending on socket.io.
I'm sending some short data to every single client 10-200 times per second and it seems like the server is okay with that. But the client side like google chrome is crashing or being very slow frequently. I need to fix that browser stability.

Comment: what do you do with the data received? The socket should nto be the problem.

Comment: I'm doing some ui updates and showing the data to user. Well, I figure out that problem by resting the datas about 500ms before sending clients. That's mean is I'm sending the last data updates to clients every 500ms by stacking them. In this way clients getting updates twice in munite and they are not crashing. Thanks for the response!

Comment: well if receiving 200 updates per second means 200+ dom updates it will stop the browser if you dont update the right way, you can use requestAinmationframe and a queue to throttle the dom (you should really do that either way)

Comment: Hi @PaulScheltema, after some time I realized that when I'm come back the page after hanging out in another tab for a while, the page becomes unresponsive even if I use requestAnimationFrame(). So what do you suggest?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well as Paul Scheltema said seems like the problem comes from a lot of dom manipulating requests at the same time. You can see the solution above.